# use-package dependecy loop

Tags: init-file, package, use-package

I use use-package in my `init.el` and use `:ensure` to make sure packages are installed. However after every package update via `package.el`, it tells me some packages are no longer needed and can be removed, even though those packages are actually needed. If I remove them via `M-x package-autoremove`, they get installed the next time I open Emacs. Does this have something to do with the order in which they are added in `package.el`?

For example, helm has been added to my init file like this:

```
;; helm-mode by default
(use-package helm
  :ensure t
  :diminish helm-mode
  :config
  (helm-mode 1)
  :bind (("M-x" . helm-M-x)
         ("C-x C-f" . helm-find-files)
         ("C-c f" . helm-recentf)
         ("C-x b" . helm-mini)
         ("C-x C-b" . helm-buffers-list)))
```

However it gets installed as a dependency. The same happens for `company-mode`, `helm-ag` etc.

Comment: If you can make a minimal example of a package with dependencies that Emacs thinks are not needed, this would be a great bug report to `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my `package-selected-packages` variable. Somehow due to the order of the packages, `package.el` was listing some packages as dependencies. Deleting the variable and restarting Emacs fixed the listing.